# Can you save changes that you make in the browser to your local HTML file via JavaScript or php?

Tags: javascript, php, server, editing

In a nutshell, I have a website template on my computer that I constantly have to add/remove paragraphs, change colors of headers, change images, etc. in order to build new websites to place on a server. For a quick solution of editing these, I thought of writing JavaScript that prompts the user for their choice of colors, images, paragraphs they would like to remove, etc. and, once submitted, makes those changes in the browser (somewhat like a cdm). Of course, once I refresh the browser, all of the user's changes will be lost, unless I just copy the new code from Inspector Tools, and replace the old website template code with it.

What I want to know is, is it possible to write code in either php or JavaScript where you can open your local index.html file in a browser, have the browser prompt you for specific values (such as what hex color value do you want all of the header elements to be?), takes the values you input and saves them into the local index.html file? This way, I can just take my newly edited local file and place it on the server as a new product. I know this is a bit of a weird request, sorry in advance if it's not too clear.

Comment: Yes it is, but amending your `index.html` file on the fly I would consider rather dangerous. One mistake and your home page is toast.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and maybe try to improve your question. I'm not sure what you are aiming at. You have a local template `index.html` file that you edit often and then upload. How do you edit the file? Why not open it in a code editor, edit it (use search and replace etc. for convenience) and then save a copy of the modified version? Or am I completely missing your point?

Answer (score 0):

> This way, I can just take my newly edited local file and place it on the server as a new product. I know this is a bit of a weird request, sorry in advance if it's not too clear.

Is this new product a new separate website...like a new website template a user can install?
I have a hunch that its just a "new product" in a list of products in some kind of webstore. If its just a product in a store...then your whole approach is "wrong" in my opinion. Either way, you can use node.js/php + database to save users choices and generate your html on the server side.
Ive done this before for a client just so he could fine tune a webpage with colors/fonts/paddings live, and see the results immediately.

My quick solution was basically like this.

```
// load user choices from the database
landingpage = Database.landing_page.find({userId: 1});
// use simple templating engine to output values based on user choices
<html>
    <img src="{{landingpage.logoUrl}}">
    {{#if landingpage.paragraph1}}
    <p style="color: {{landingpage.paragraph1_color}}">{{landingpage.paragraph1}}</p>
    {{/if}}
    {{#if landingpage.paragraph2}}
    <p style="color: {{landingpage.paragraph2_color}}">{{landingpage.paragraph2}}</p>
    {{/if}}
</html>

// after user has filled in all the required configuration options, i could then open the page and see the rendered page html.
```

Each page also had an extra template with input fields, so if user wanted to edit a page, he could open that "special" template in the browser and click on any element on a page. This would then prompt him with all the editable properties for that element.

for example, to make the above template editable i would copy it and add click listeners.

```
<html>
    <img src="{{landingpage.logoUrl}}" onClick="promptLogoUrl()">
    {{#if landingpage.paragraph1}}
    <p style="color: {{landingpage.paragraph1_color}}" onClick="promptP1Color()">
        {{landingpage.paragraph1}}
    </p>
    {{/if}}
    {{#if landingpage.paragraph2}}
    <p style="color: {{landingpage.paragraph2_color}}" onClick="promptP2Color()">
        {{landingpage.paragraph2}}
    </p>
    {{/if}}
</html>
// the prompts would use ajax to save the value user entered in prompt with the appropriate element id/name/label
```

This is a simplified example. In my real use-case, my templates used a naming convention/pattern so that I could use 1 function to save all the properties user entered.

Your question is a yes and no question, so i will give a short yes or no answer.
Yes - you can save changes to your local html via javascript/php.